# how to split single cell into multiple row of same cell in excel

Tags: excel, split

how to split single cell into multiple row of same cell in Excel:

[image]

like if we have a cell value like this:

```
10.1.2.8 20.3.2.5 10.1.1.8 22.1.2.3
```

then need to display them like

```
10.1.2.8
20.3.2.5
10.1.1.8
22.1.2.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the `space` with a `LF` and set the cell format to `wrap text`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",CHAR(10))
```

[image]

Comment: THANKS for reply, =SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",CHAR(10)) function just remove the space and display the value same without space.

Comment: @BilalKhan Read the entire answer.  You omitted to: **… set the cell format to wrap text**